# 'Dialog(android.content.Context)' in 'android.app.Dialog' cannot be applied to '(com.example.mytractivities.HomeFragment)'

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, android-dialog

In my program I have a bottom nagivattin menu with three fragments. The first fragment (HomeFragment) has a button which opens a dialog. This dialog as you can see belowhas two buttons, a cancel button and an ok button. If the user clicks the ok button, the chronometer should start and the progressbar should also start with its progress. And my question is, what i should pass in as context of the dialog. I tried getActivity(), but the crashes after clicking the button. Heres the code:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment
{
    Chronometer chronometer;
    Button btn_beginDay;
    Button btn_enterNewActivity;
    Dialog dialog;
    Spinner spinner;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    ImageView circle;
    TextView tv_timeOfCircle;
    private int progress = 0;
    private long pauseOffset;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, 
@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, 
container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        chronometer = view.findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
        chronometer.setFormat("%s");
        chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        chronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
                long time = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase();
                int h = (int) (time / 3600000);
                int m = (int) (time - h * 3600000) / 60000;
                int s = (int) (time - h * 3600000 - m * 60000) / 1000;
                String t = (h < 10 ? "0" + h : h) + ":" + (m < 10 ? "0" + m : m) + ":" + (s < 10 ? "0" + s : s);
            chronometer.setText(t);
        }
    });

    chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
    chronometer.setText("00:00:00");

    CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(86400*1000,1000)
    {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
        {
            progress = progress + 1;
            progressBar.setProgress(progress);
            progressBar.setMax(10000);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish()
        {

        }
    };

    btn_enterNewActivity = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_enterNewActivity);
    btn_beginDay = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_beginDay);
    btn_beginDay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog = new Dialog(HomeFragment.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_template);
            EditText EnterNewActivity = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.write);
            Button OK = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_OK);
            OK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String firstActivity = EnterNewActivity.getText().toString();
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), firstActivity + " has been added to your Activities", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                    chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - pauseOffset);
                    chronometer.start();
                    dialog.cancel();
                    countDownTimer.start();
                    btn_beginDay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btn_enterNewActivity.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
            });
            Button Cancel = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_Cancel);
            Cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            dialog.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
}


}
```

Comment: when you set  dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());  do you also have a crash but what a error?

Comment: Following error occurs: Note: C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\MyTractivities\app\src\main\java\com\example\mytractivities\MainActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.